# I can't install minetest!

Tags: package-management

I used to have Minetest but they recently came out with a newer version. I tried getting it but it wouldn't update. So I uninstalled Minetest. When I typed in "sudo apt-get install minetest" it said:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  minetest

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Need to get 0 B/8 656 kB of archives.

After this operation, 26,4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 271398 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack .../minetest_0.4.15-ppa4~ubuntu16.10.1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking minetest (0.4.15-ppa4~ubuntu16.10.1) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/minetest_0.4.15-

ppa4~ubuntu16.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/appdata/minetest.appdata.xml', which is also in package minetest-data 0.4.14+repack-5

dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/minetest_0.4.15-ppa4~ubuntu16.10.1_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

*I don't know what to do. I have looked it up but haven't found anything useful.

Comment: I have not tried this, and you should wait for a better answer to come along just in case, but maybe `sudo rm /usr/share/appdata/minetest.appdata.xml` will work.

Comment: Remove the old minetest and minetest-data packages first before upgrading - there may be upgrade headaches if they changed the packaging somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what someone said in the comments and purged the minetest-data. Then went to Synaptic and found Minetest. I was able to download it. I now have Minetest.